# New section/entry can't go live

Tags: templating, sections

I've created a new section, with one entry. When I want to live preview the entry, the live preview button isn't there.

I've read this is because my new section doesn't have an active template? How do I resolve this?

I'm very new to this!

Answer (score 2):

Have you already made up an html template for this section?

If so you should check if you assigned it right.
Go to: Settings>Sections>(your new section you want to assign) and check the entry template. It should be something like (folder you made the html template in if there is any)/(name of file)

Without any written HTML its not possible to have a live preview as it doesn't output anything.

If thats alright could you post some pictures of your Folders and your back office?

Comment: Hi Justin - I haven't made an html template yet, how do I do that? Is there a sample one I can use? I inherited the website and have only had to make edits up until this point. Thanks!

Comment: Hi!, You have to create a folder inside your craft/templates folder. Name it what ever you prefer and then create an .html file inside there. I would recommend naming it index.html. When you are done with that follow the steps in my answer to assign it to your template. Just a quick question are you familiar with writing your own code or are you new to this too (if you're not I don't mean to be rude)? What kind of section do you need to create plus is the site already live or anything like this. What kinde of changes do you need to make?

Comment: Completely new to all of this including code so thanks for helping. We're a small charity, the site is already live and I want to add a 'Support Us' page to it. Ideally this 'Support Us' section will have three entries when finished. I've gone to Settings and added a new  Section which all seems good (if I'm using the wrong lingo, I hope this still makes sense!) When I click on the world icon next to entry, this message appears: Unable to find the template "_layout" in "404" at line 19. I think I'm failing at the first step...  I can't see the craft/templates folder...

Comment: Well if you're new to Coding to I should ask the IT company that made the website in the first place if they can add one. Or maybe someone's relative who got some coding experience.
You could have look in your "entries" section and see if there is any template under "structures" If that is so you could make a "Support us" page there if the site is setup well. What kind of template did you get? Was it premade or custom made by someone or an company? If its premade bought from internet could you tell me which?

Comment: I've gone back to the company to ask - I believe they custom made it for us (again before I started!). It's a learning curve but a useful one -  thanks for your help!

Comment: I hate to say this I really do but you might need to just hire a developer ... if you have never written any HTML or coded simple basic web pages of any kind then trying to add to an existing CMS driven website on any platform will likely take the most intelligent person days to learn all the moving parts. Not to discourage you, but the initial learning curve in web development (from scratch) is quite a ride!

Comment: @Georgina register for the Craft Slack community, it’s a good place to ask the smaller questions you come along while working with Craft. https://craftcms.com/community

Comment: @Georgina what Josh is saying might indeed be the best option or as I said maybe someone you know with some experience in coding but If the site isn't setup properly it is not a good option time wise to start finishing it yourself. Its not an easy start to learn but if you know how to code you're hooked and thats good in my opion. Carl's suggestion is in the good way too as there are many people there to help and assist in a quicker way then stackexchange.